trying to deploy a nextjs site to vercel using pnpm and monorepo is hiting a bug
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/69950
I am hiting the above issue and i really cant figure what is causing it
I am trying to push a blog site i did as a monorepo to vercel unfortunately i am getting a Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/next-server.js' bug as explained in that link above. I was hoping you folks might have some insights on what could be causing it.

works fine in dev mode
works perfect when built locally and started using next start
3.1 when i push to vercel i am getting the above error
3.2 all other pages of the site are working perfectly when i deploy it. its only the blog that has this issue.

❯ ./node_modules/.bin/vercel version
Vercel CLI 33.2.0


here is how i am deploying it
running from the root of the mono repo
echo deploying ... \
&& pnpm --filter app-site vercel:build \
&& pnpm --filter app-site vercel:deploy \

relevant seciont in ./apps/app-site/package.json
...
    "vercel:build": "vercel build",
    "vercel:deploy": "vercel deploy --prebuilt"

my directory tree
❯ tree -d -L 2 -I node_modules 
.
├── apps
│   ├── app-dash
│   ├── app-draw
│   ├── app-pres
│   └── app-site
├── bldz
├── cue.mod
├── packages
│   ├── config-eslint
│   ├── config-tailwind-js
│   ├── config-tailwind-ts
│   ├── config-typescript
│   ├── lib-auth
│   ├── lib-r3f-demos
│   ├── lib-r3f-scene
│   └── lib-react-ui



Best Regards
